# Converting Stereo to Mono using TarsosDSP does not work

Tags: java, wav, tarsosdsp

I would like to use some features of TarsosDSP on sound data. The incoming data is Stereo, but Tarsos does only support mono, so I tried to transfer it to mono as follows, but the result still sounds like stereo data interpreted as mono, i.e. the conversion via `MultichannelToMono` doesn't seem to have any effect, although its implementation looks good upon a quick glance.

```
@Test
public void testPlayStereoFile() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {
    AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromFile(FILE,4096,0);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new MultichannelToMono(dispatcher.getFormat().getChannels(), false));
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new AudioPlayer(dispatcher.getFormat()));
    dispatcher.run();
}
```

Is there anything that I do wrong here? Why does the `MultichannelToMono` processor not transfer the data to mono?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found which works is to use the Java Audio System for performing this conversion before sending the data to TarsosDSP, it seems it does not convert the framesize correctly

I found the following snippet at https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26925195/java-stereo-to-mono-conversion-unsupported-conversion-error.html which I use to convert to mono before applying more advanced audio transformations with TarsosDSP.

```
public static AudioInputStream convertToMono(AudioInputStream sourceStream) {
    AudioFormat sourceFormat = sourceStream.getFormat();

    // is already mono?
    if(sourceFormat.getChannels() == 1) {
        return sourceStream;
    }

    AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(
            sourceFormat.getEncoding(),
            sourceFormat.getSampleRate(),
            sourceFormat.getSampleSizeInBits(),
            1,
            // this is the important bit, the framesize needs to change as well,
            // for framesize 4, this calculation leads to new framesize 2
            (sourceFormat.getSampleSizeInBits() + 7) / 8,
            sourceFormat.getFrameRate(),
            sourceFormat.isBigEndian());
    return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, sourceStream);
}
```